# Missing data fields from tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am Using `PowerBI` Desktop Direct Query on `SQL` database

When the data is loaded into PowerBI Desktop I can see that there are certain fields missing from the table. When I view in SQL Server Manager Studio I can see the entire table.

Is there a known reason why all fields in the table would not be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the **Query Editor** window (hit **Edit Queries**) - steps can be added to any Query to remove columns, or specify a selected set of columns.

It could also be that the columns were added to the SQL table after the Power BI Query was built.  For that scenario you just need to use **Refresh Preview** in the Query Editor window and they will flow through to the Power BI table.